How Can I Perform Real-Time UMTS RRC Packet Analysis in C++ Without Writing to PCAP Files?
I have a UMTS packet log, and I’ve written a C++ program using the pcapplusplus library to send these packets continuously to my loopback interface. I have another C++ application that listens to the loopback interface and captures the packets.
In my second application, I collect incoming packets into batches of 200,000 and then analyze each batch separately. The goal of my analysis is to detect RRC (Radio Resource Control) messages within these UMTS packets and extract specific information from them.
Currently, my method involves writing each batch to a .pcapng file and then using the following command to extract the RRC packets:
QProcess tsharkProcess;
tsharkProcess.start("tshark", QStringList() << "-r" << fileName << "-Y" << "rrc" << "-T" << "json");

However, this approach is time-consuming because the packets are coming in at a high rate, and I need to achieve real-time analysis.
What can I do to improve the performance of my analysis and avoid writing packets to a .pcapng file for real-time RRC packet detection?
I’ve explored alternative methods, such as reading and understanding the tshark and Wireshark code, particularly the packet-umts_rlc.c file, to replicate the RRC packet detection. However, this turned out to be too complex to implement directly.

You can write pcap format data to a named pipe for WireShark to read. see: https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Pipes for details
